# NSArray not iterating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop, int

I am trying to iterate through an `NSArray` with a for loop. The result only returns the last value in the array even though the int variable `i` is printing correctly (0,1,2...).

Also, if I set iteration to say `5`, I will get the 6th object in the array, which is correct. I did this to try to narrow down the scope of possible causes.

Any ideas?

```
int i;
int j;
Buffer *vocalBuffer; 
for (i=0; i < numberOfBuffers; i++){ // loop through every vocal buffer

    Buffer *mixedBuffer = [[Buffer alloc] init];
    int array[sizeLoopBuff];
    mixedBuffer.buffer = array;
    mixedBuffer.numFrames = sizeLoopBuff;
    NSLog(@"Vocal buffer number --> %i", i);
    NSInteger iteration = i;
    vocalBuffer = [arrayOfVocalBuffers objectAtIndex:iteration]; // grab the vocal buffer

    for (j=0; j < sizeLoopBuff; j++){ // run through a beat loop cycle.
        mixedBuffer.buffer[j] = loopBuffer.buffer[j]; // add the beats to return buffer.
        if (j > insertPoint && j < insertPoint+ vocalBuffer.numFrames){
            mixedBuffer.buffer[j] = loopBuffer.buffer[j] + vocalBuffer.buffer[j-insertPoint];
        }
    }
    [mutArray addObject:mixedBuffer];
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  You say the result returns the last value in the array? If the result is "`vocalBuffer`", then of course it'd retrieve the last objectAtIndex value.  Or is the result thing you're looking for something else?

Comment: This is not good: `int array[sizeLoopBuff]; mixedBuffer.buffer = array;`.  You are pointing a property in a dynamically allocated object at a data block that is local to the for-loop.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Hmmm... maybe I am making an obvious mistake I can't see. I am trying to create an array of `mixedBuffers`, each one containing a `vocalBuffer` mixed with a `loopBuffer`. Each `vocalBuffer` is different, yet my output is an array of `mixed buffer`s each containing the last `vocalBuffer`.

Comment: @PhillipMills Sounds good. Any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: Allocate the buffer dynamically, with `malloc` or one of its friends, maybe inside the Buffer init method.  (?)

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks! You should put it in an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As figured out in the comments, the use of a pointer to stack storage has some problems. One is that while it's in scope, its content is overwritten by each use within a loop; individual objects with pointers to it do not have unique copies.

The other problem is that once the method returns and its stack space isn't needed (as far as the runtime is concerned), there's no predicting what will be done with the space.

The necessary behavior of having a unique buffer per object suggests that the object should allocate its own buffer dynamically when created.

Comment: You might also consider having your `Buffer` class own an `NSMutableData` for the `buffer` attribute. You might have a method `-(void*)bufferBytes { return [self.buffer mutableBytes]; }` to provide easy access to the buffer bytes. The reason is to allow for easier memory management, especially if you're using ARC (which I hope you are or the code leaks).